# AppFabric DataCache GetValues by keys?

Tags: c#, caching, redis, appfabric, azure-appfabric

How can I use AppFabric DataCache and **get values** by keys?

eg. I want to do:

```
string[] keys = new []{"key1","key2", ...,"keyLast" }
object[] values = factory.GetCache("MyCache").Get(keys);
```

This seems like a very fundamental operation, I am hoping there is a way to do this without roundtripping to the backing store.

P.s. I know redis ServiceStack implementation supports this out of the box, for my use case this is a mandatory feature in deciding which technology to adopt for my company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BulkGet` method ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff424905.aspx)) can do this. It accepts an `IEnumerable<string>` of the keys and the name of a region to query (which could be the System region, which you can get with the `GetSystemRegionName` method), and returns an `IEnumerable<KeyValue<string, object>>` of the keys and values (so you know which value goes with which key). Alternatively, if you're using regions, you can use the GetObjectsInRegion method, which will return the same structure (`IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`) containing all the objects cached in that region.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I must have missed that one when going through the API.